# how to extract the previous or next string of matched with regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

```
final String str = "I want to get previous or next string";
final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("or").matcher(str);
if(matcher.find()){
System.out.println(str.substring(matcher.end()).trim());
}
```

I want to get:"previous" or "next"  strings

```
output: next string
```

Comment: Why not use a positive look behind for "or" and capture `"next String"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score -1):

Group your regex and iterate through groups from the mathcher class. Google it regex grouping and iteration in java. get sample and do it.